# Introspect graphql schema using *.graphqls files

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Currently I'm using com.graphql-java-kickstart library and spring boot for running graphql server. And now for contract testing I would like to have ability to generate json schema, like I have when doing request '/graphql/schema.json'. But without running server, only based on .graphqls files.

Are there any jvm-based(preferable) tools that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution using graphql-java library. Maybe it would be useful for somebody except me.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper()
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(inputDir, new String[]{"graphqls"}, true);

    SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();
    TypeDefinitionRegistry mergedDefinitoionRegistry = new TypeDefinitionRegistry();
    files.forEach(file -> {
        TypeDefinitionRegistry typeDefinitionRegistry = schemaParser.parse(file);
        mergedDefinitoionRegistry.merge(typeDefinitionRegistry);
    });

    SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();
    GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(mergedDefinitoionRegistry, RuntimeWiring.MOCKED_WIRING);

    GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
    ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(IntrospectionQuery.INTROSPECTION_QUERY);

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(executionResult);
```